# Modify values of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have this dictionary:

```
my_dicts =  {'key1': 'true', 'key2': 'true'}
```

and I want to replace true with `True`

How could I do that.

I've tried to do:

```
for t in my_dicts:
    t.update((k, "True") for k, v in t.items() if v == "true")
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: `for t in my_dicts` means that you're going through the keys in `my_dicts` i.e. `t` will always be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {key: True if value == 'true' else value for key, value in my_dicts.items()}
{'key1': True, 'key2': True}
```

Other answers mention using `dict.update`, if you go this route, there's no need to build the complete dictionary again, you just need to replace the keys for which `value == 'true'`:

```
>>> my_dicts.update({key: True for key, value in my_dicts.items() if value == 'true'})
>>> my_dicts
{'key1': True, 'key2': True}
```

Answer (score 2):

Francisco's answer is good -- it's how i would do it.

For another inline solution that modifies the dictionary inline rather than create a new one (which would be useful if the dictionary is huge):

```
d.update((k, v if v != 'true' else True) for k,v in d.items())
```

Comment: Francisco's answer seems the same as yours, mate?

Comment: not quite -- Francisco's (original) solution creates a new dictionary (so now there are two dictionaries in memory) -- whereas this one (and ShadowRanger's latter solution) modify the original dictionary in-place

Answer (score 1):

As [Francisco notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310473/364696), a `dict` comprehension will work to make a new `dict` with replaced keys. You can also just modify the `dict` in place, either with an explicit loop:

```
for k, v in my_dicts.items():
    if v == 'true':
        my_dicts[k] = True
```

or by using the `dict` comprehension and updating the original `dict` with the result:

```
my_dicts.update({k: True if v == 'true' else v for k, v in my_dicts.items()})
```

The first approach is likely faster in general, since it avoids the temporary `dict`, and doesn't even try to update keys unless the value is the `"true"` string you want to replace.

To be clear, it's *normally* unsafe to modify a `dict` as you iterate it, so you're excused if you worry about the first loop. But in this case, it's fine; the danger with mutating a `dict` as you iterate it comes from adding or removing keys, but since every key you set already exists in the `dict`, you're only updating the value of an existing key (which is safe/legal), not changing the set of keys themselves (which will bite you).

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying your code too much, here is my suggestion:

```
my_dicts =  {'key1': 'true', 'key2': 'true'}

for key in my_dicts:
    if my_dicts[key] == 'true': my_dicts[key] = 'True'

print("After:")
for key, value in my_dicts.iteritems():
    print(key + " = " + my_dicts[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use **json.loads** to convert string to bool type.

```
import json
my_dicts =  {'key1': 'true', 'key2': 'true'}

for key, value in my_dicts.items():
    if value == 'true':
        my_dicts[key] = json.loads(value)

print(my_dicts)
```

**Output:**

```
{'key1': True, 'key2': True}
```